# create Entity Tag, but it is null

Tags: java, http, jersey, uri, response

In my Jersey Rest Service i tried to create an entity tag with:

```
String content = 12sdfs-345dsdfsdf-231yscysd;
String createdContent = create(content);
return Response.created(createdUri).entity(createdContent).build();
```

like its written in the jersey documentation. But `createdContent` is `null`. Whats wrong?

The full code is:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response postObject(@FormParam("number") int number) {

    ObjectDTO c = new ObjectDTO();;
    c.setNumber(number);


    String generatedId = generateID();
    c.setId(generatedId);
    c.setOwner(sec.getUserPrincipal().getName());
    return postAndGetResponse(c);
}


private Response postAndGetResponse(ObjectDTO object) {
    Response res;
    System.out.println(object);
    if(ObjectDAO.instance.getObjectDao().containsKey(object.getId())) {
        res = Response.serverError().status(409).build();
    } else {
        System.out.println(object);
        System.out.println(object.getId());
        String createdContent = create(object.getId());
        System.out.println(createdContent);
        res = Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()).entity(createdContent).build();
        ObjectDAO.instance.getObjectDao().put(object.getId(), object);
    }
    return res;
}
```

edit:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e188

chapter 2.5

Comment: im so stupid. the create method made an function stub. didnt noticed this... so how can i create my entity tag to get it into the response? the jersey documentation just says create(string)... but nothing about this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an entity tag simply call `new EntityTag(string)`. But what are you trying to achieve in the code above? The entity tag should be attached to the header, not to the body.